# how to order set of objects based on array of integers

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class called Variable

```
Class Variable{ private String name; private int[] domain; //...etc}
```

which represents variable in specific structure (constraint satisfaction problem).

I have instantiated set of variables in ArrayList< Variable > and filled up an array of integers.

```
 ArrayList<Variable> vars=new ArrayList<Variable>();
 Variable a=new Variable("A",new int[]{1,2});
 vars.add(a);
 // Define all variables;
 int[] cons=new int[vars.size()];
  for(int i=0;i<cons.length;i++)
    cons[i]=number_of_constraints(vars.get(i));
    // cons contains number of involved constraints for each variable
```

Now I need to sort them descending based on the number of constraints.

In other words: Given list of Objects    `[(A,{1,2}) , (B,{3,4}) , (C,{5,6}) ]` and an array of integers `cons={1,2,0}` how to sort the list of objects descending based on the array of integers?

Comment: Nice rep on [academia.se], by the way

Comment: What are the sort critera?

Comment: What is the expected output? `[ (B,{3,4}) , (C,{5,6}) , (A,{1,2}) ]` (`cons` being a permutation of indexes into the list)?

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry I have edited the question. I need to sort them descending (highest comes first).

Comment: @Seteropere, so you want `C,B,A` (ignoring `cons`), or `A,C,B` (sorting `cons` descending)?

Comment: @JanDvorak I mean sorting the variables based on the number of constraints (i.e. their corresponding values in the array). From highest to lowest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sorted collection like a `TreeSet`

```
class Variable {

    private String name;
    private int[] domain;
};
final Set<Variable> variables = new TreeSet<Variable>( new Comparator<Variable>() {

    public int compare(Variable o1, Variable o2) {
        //Do comparison here
        //return -1 if o1 is less than o2
        //1 if o1 is greater than o2
        //0 if they are the same
    }
});
```

Now you have a sorted `Set` of your `Variable`s.  This is guaranteed to always be sorted.

Comment: "This is implemented as a Red-Black" Please remove this part, no-where in the spec it says that TreeSet is implemented using Red-Black trees, even if it is in practice there is no guarantee it will on any valid Java implementation. The only guarantee is that add/remove/contains are log(n). There are plenty of tree structures that do that (AVL trees for example also do log(n) add/remove/contains)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to keep Class `Variable` intact, the following code will sort the given `vars` outside:

```
   Collections.sort(vars, new Comparator<Variable>() {
       public int compare(Variable var1, Variable var2) {
           return var2.number_of_constraints() - var1.number_of_constraints();
    }});
```

If you can change Class `Variable`, let it implement interface `Comparable`:

```
class Variable implements Comparable<Variable> {
    //...

    public int compareTo(Variable other) {
        return this.number_of_constraints() -
               other.number_of_constraints();
    }
}
```

Then you can sort `vars` by:

```
Collections.sort(vars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Variable class should implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, 
When it does you should implement the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

After that you can sort it by calling the [Collection.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method.

If you want to sort by a permutation if your indexes that's just a matter of creating a new `ArrayList` and mapping each index to the new index (using a for loop)

Here is such a (generic) method

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> permutate(ArrayList<T> origin,int[] permutation){
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(permutation.length);
        for(int j=0;j<permutation.length;j++){
            result.add(null);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<permutation.length;i++){
            result.set(i, origin.get(permutation[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You can do `myArrayList= permutate(myArrayList, new int{1,2,3});`

Here is example usage in a more basic use case (integers):

```
public static void main(String... args){
    ArrayList<Integer> origin = new ArrayList<>(4);
    origin.add(1);
    origin.add(2);
    origin.add(3);
    origin.add(4);

    int[] per = new int[]{2,1,3,0};
    origin = permutate(origin,per);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(origin.toArray())); //prints [3,2,4,1], your permutation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as a `Variable` contains `numOfConstraints`, according to your code, you can make your `Variable` class implement `Comparable` interface, like

```
public class Variuable implements Comparable<Variable> {

    private int numOfConstraints;

    public int compareTo(Variable other){
        if(this == other) { return 0; }
        return (numOfConstraints == other.numOfConstraint) ? 0 : ((numOfConstraints > other.numOfConstraint) ? 1 : -1);
    }

}
```

And then use the utility method `java.util.Collections.sort(vars);`, that's it.